# Ubuntu 12.10 cannot detect windows 8 in uefi mode when installing

Tags: dual-boot, 12.10, windows-8, detect

I've installed Windows 8 64 bit on UEFI . Now I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 on UEFI too. I used a usb flash drive to boot in UEFI mode and started install, but in "installation type" screen, it was unable to detect any os.  I tried Ubuntu without installing it and: 
 
1. In uefi boot mode, I cannot mount any partition.
2. In Legacy boot mode, I can mount all partitions.
Windows 8 OS partition is primary partition.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it possible you are working with an encrypted partition? If it is encrypted then Ubuntu won't be able to see what is on the disk

Comment: I think my partition is not an encrypted partition. I've never use a tool to encrypt my partition.Furthermore, in legacy mode I can mount all partitions.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. Are you using an SSD? See [this guide](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware) and the separate post on problems with SSDs [here](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/06/why-is-windows-8-on-ssd-invisible-to-ubuntu-12-10s-installer/). The comments on those posts might be helpfful as well - it partially depends on the BIOS setup you have.